# iPhone 4 jailbroken

Tags: iphone, jailbreak, cellular-carriers

I have a jail broken iPhone 4 (allowing me to use it as unlocked) but I have no idea if this phone was initially locked to a network in the first place before it was jailbroken.

I have entered my IMEI on numerous websites and it comes coming back as being unlocked. Is this because it is jailbroken, or is the phone actually unlocked?

Answer (score 1):

If the IMEI is coming up unlocked, it's because the phone was unlocked at the carrier level. Jailbreak unlocking doesn't change that, it merely overrides the lock on the phone.